# How to remove the last slash content inside JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example the contents of my json  would look like`{"path": "/home/data/files/access"}`. How can I remove  /access and replace JSON with `{"path": "/home/data/files"}`

Comment: Convert the json to an array or a string and after yor task is done convert it back to json.

Comment: You stringify the Json- Use lastindexof() method to get the last / - Use substring to remove the final part.

Comment: This is not a valid JSON, Do you realy ment JSON or a simple JS object. Please fix your question: `{"path": "/home/data/files/access"}` @KrishnaPrashatt You mean parse the JSON right?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt can you please give me one example. I'm new vibe to coding

Comment: @Bellian that is exactly what I meant and thats the functionality of stringify() method .....ravan one - already people have given the answers, so I dont think I would clutter the comment section

Comment: @reporter Can please explain me in detail. I'm new to javascript and angular. It would be helpful if you explain me in fiddle . Thanks

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt That is not true. `JSON.stringify()` will create a JSON from data and `JSON.parse()` will convert a JSON to the data. I guess there is a bit of a confusion what JSON is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: Thank You for everyone. I can learn lot of things from here

Comment: @Bellian.. I think that you have understood the concept interchanged. JSON.parse() will render a JSON type javascript object from string. JSON.stringify() will convert the JSON type javascript object to string.            [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp)                                                   [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

Comment: Thanks @Bellian . yeah understood. :)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var obj = {"path": "/home/data/files/access"};
obj.path=obj.path.substring(0, obj.path.lastIndexOf("/"));
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split by '/', remove the last element with array.pop then join by '/':

```js
var data = { path: '/home/data/files/access' };
data.path = data.path.split('/');
data.path.pop();
data.path = data.path.join('/');
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `split()`, `pop()` and `join()`. I am adding this answer as an alternative to build logic in javascript.

```js
var obj = {"path": "/home/data/files/access"};
//split to create array
var arr = obj.path.split('/');
//remove last element of array
arr.pop();
//join the elements of array with /
var res = arr.join('/');
//replace the path property of obj
obj.path = res;
console.log(obj);
```